# Use Rails ERB tag in Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

Using Rails 4. I have the following:

```
module ShopsHelper
  def edit_shop(shop)
    link_to edit_shop_path(shop), target: "_blank" do
      raw("<i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Update")
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I use `<i class='fa fa-edit'></i>` which is for Font Awesome, but [Font Awesome gem](http://%20github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass) provides the `<%= icon "edit" %>` which is cleaner. How can I use the `icon` tag in the helper?

Comment: Have you tried just calling the icon method inside the block? e.g. `icon "edit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the helper, as stated in the docs:

```
icon "edit"
# => <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
```

The rails helpers work as any other method, and the returned values are replaced in the ERB templates.

When you use one of the form helpers as a wrapper for a block (... do %>) rails closes the tag after the block.

```
link_to edit_shop_path(shop), target: "_blank" do
  raw("<i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Update")
end
```

Turns into:

```
<a .... >
  <i></i>
</a>
```

You should be able to replace the:

```
<i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Update
```

With the:

```
icon "edit"
```

---

```
module ShopsHelper
  def edit_shop(shop)
    link_to edit_shop_path(shop), target: "_blank" do
      raw icon('edit', 'Update')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Using https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass instead, but found out I could use `icon('flag', 'Font Awesome', id: 'my-icon', class: 'strong')`. Please update your answer to include my findings. I will mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: I updated it but you can answer yourself and I will upvote anyway.